# Linq- left join on dbset

Tags: linq

I have 2 tables:

```
A {
    IDA
    propA1
    propA2
}
B {
    IDA,
    IDB,
    propB1,
    propB2
}
```

I want to get all records from table A such that IDA is not contained in table B where IDB = "someValue".
The query is using linq.

Comment: so you don't want a left join...

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using Linq on C#.

```
var someIDAs = B.Where(b => b.IDB == "someValue").Select(b => b.IDA);
var result = A.Where(a => !someIDAs.Contains(a.IDA));
```

**Edit:** And, as Florian says, that's something different than what is called *left join*.